# Simple animation text color change

Tags: unity, animation

I apologize in advanced if this is a trivial ask, but I am wondering if it is possible to use an animation to change the color of a Text element from teal -> white without any lerp, i.e the color instantly changes. My current animation is only the one frame at 0:00 where I do the switch, but you can still see that the color is lerping even though it is the first and only frame. Am I missing something simple or should I just script the change? Fixing the problem is easy (Trivial to script), but I am just curious if there is something in the animation I can change to not have the color lerp?

I posted the question [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-animation-text-color-change.555499/) as well, but I never have any luck posting on the Unity forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your animation timeline, right-click on your keyframes and set their tangents to **Broken -> Constant**, [as described in the docs on editing curves](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingCurves.html).

This ensures there's a discrete jump from the old value to the new when the animation reaches the keyframe, instead of a blend in between.

[image: Unity documentation screenshot showing constant tangent mode.]

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks for baring with me.